# group by in linq doesn't show the expected result

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have these tables :

```
TestPackagejoint(id,testpackageid,jointid)
Joint(id,endid)
```

I create a joint between `testpackage` and `joint` and joint based on `jointid,id` .

I want to group the value based on `endid` and `testpackageid`,and count of `endid` or example :

```
testpackageid       endid       count
1                     2          3
4                     2          1
1                     3          2
```

So i write this query

```
 var q = (from i in _ctx.TestPackageJoints
                where i.TestPackageId == Id
                join joint1 in _ctx.Joints on i.JointId equals joint1.Id
                group new {joint1.EndId,i.TestPackageId} by new { i, joint1}
                into g1
                select new
                {
                    testpackid = g1.Key.i.TestPackageId,
                    Count = g1.Count(),
                    endid = g1.Key.joint1.EndId
                }).ToList();
```

But the result :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must understand what want to get. You want to get testpackid and endid, so it's correct to group them. You also want to group by testpackid and endid, why do you group by new {i, ...} here.

Try

```
group new {joint1.EndId,i.TestPackageId} by new {joint1.EndId,i.TestPackageId}
```

Or

```
join ...
let item = new {joint1.EndId,i.TestPackageId}
group item by item
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query ought to be:

```
var query =
    from tpj in _ctx.TestPackageJoints
    join j in _ctx.Joints on tpj.JointId equals j.Id
    where tpj.TestPackageId == id
    group 1 by new { tpj.TestPackageId, j.EndId } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.TestPackageId,
        g.Key.EndId,
        Count = g.Count(),
    };
```

The `group by` clause is in the form `group [object] by [key]`. You included a `TestPackageJoint` object as part of the key which likely doesn't define equality so it produced a group for every pairing.